# Show all variables available in jinja templates

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

How can I show all available variables available in jinja templates?

I'm following the manual, I get this output:

`'"hostvars": "<ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVars object at 0x7f634cc78dd0>"'`.

The command is:

`PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR=true ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=false ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS='-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i /home/flav/.vagrant.d/boxes/archlinux-VAGRANTSLASH-base/0/virtualbox/vagrant_private_key -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s' ansible -vvvv --connection=ssh --timeout=30 --extra-vars=ansible_ssh_user='vagrant' -i inventory_virtual.py -m debug -a "var=hostvars" $1`

I'm using ansible 2.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed my problem by using the advices from the already existing issue: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/13838